# Debugging options w/ Python, Flask and Sublime Text 2

Tags: python, flask, sublimetext2

I have just switched to Sublime Text 2 for my Python development. I usually do web programming with the Flask micro framework.

What are my debugging options with this combination, and how do I set it up? I'm working on Windows 7.

Answer (score 10):

Use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html):

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

(or the even better [pdb++](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdbpp/))

Also, Flask already include [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/) which contains an interactive JavaScript based in-browser debugger, I highly recommend you utilize it.

(if your Flask uses `uWSGI` you can check out this guide to make Werkzeug debugger work: [debugging flask application under uWSGI](http://codeseekah.com/2012/10/28/dubugging-flask-applications-under-uwsgi/))

Comment: Thx for your answer, but will it be possible to set breakpoints in code and step through it if I use pdb?

Comment: @happygoat yes, you can simply put `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` to the line you want to break at.

Comment: Real men and women use ipdb http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb (and spend a less time to do it, because arrow keys and history works)

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa thanks for the suggestions, I haven't used it before but will give it a try :)

Comment: Also worth noting; Once you've hit the break point and munged/inspected whatever you want to, you can continue the execution with __continue__ - maybe __continue()__ if you not using ipdb.